# UserWarning: There was an issue with the method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas. Calculating using eth_feeHistory

Tags: python, solidity

I am following that popular solidity course in which a lot of people encoutered the web3 gas_price problem.

Below is the original script that everyone here must be familiar.

```
from solcx import compile_standard, install_solc
import json
from web3 import Web3

with open("./SimpleStorage.sol", "r") as file:
    simple_storage_file = file.read()

    install_solc("0.6.0")
    compiled_sol = compile_standard(
        {
            "language": "Solidity",
            "sources": {"SimpleStorage.sol": {"content": simple_storage_file}},
            "settings": {
                "outputSelection": {
                    "*": {"*": ["abi", "metadata", "evm.bytecode", "evm.sourceMap"]}
                }
            },
        },
        solc_version="0.6.0",
    )
with open("compiled_code.json", "w") as file:
    json.dump(compiled_sol, file)

# Get bytecode
bytecode = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["evm"][
    "bytecode"
]["object"]

# Get ABI
abi = compiled_sol["contracts"]["SimpleStorage.sol"]["SimpleStorage"]["abi"]

# for connecting to ganache
w3 = Web3(Web3.HTTPProvider("http://127.0.0.1:7545"))
chain_id = 1337
my_address = "0xa217118d0C418048007B2f935489880F98650cC7"
private_key = "0x8a1e2a2b30b6a8886ba6dd1738af9d30237fd7e286f886495ae3528279f70f6b"

# Create the contract in python
SimpleStorage = w3.eth.contract(abi=abi, bytecode=bytecode)
print(SimpleStorage)

# Get the latest transaction
nonce = w3.eth.getTransactionCount(my_address)
print(nonce)

# 1. Build a transaction
# 2. Sign a transaction
# 3. Send a transaciton
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasprice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
print(transaction)
```

I had tried

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasprice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
```

But I still get this error

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py:656: UserWarning: There was an issue with the method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas. Calculating using eth_feeHistory.
  warnings.warn(
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 654, in max_priority_fee
    return self._max_priority_fee()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: Method eth_maxPriorityFeePerGas not supported.\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/geth_api_double.js:70:16)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:107:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/alexander/demos/web3_py_simple_storage/deploy.py", line 49, in <module>
    transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/eth_utils/decorators.py", line 18, in _wrapper
    return self.method(obj, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/contract.py", line 684, in buildTransaction
    return fill_transaction_defaults(self.web3, built_transaction)
  File "cytoolz/functoolz.pyx", line 250, in cytoolz.functoolz.curry.__call__
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 114, in fill_transaction_defaults
    default_val = default_getter(web3, transaction)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/transactions.py", line 64, in <lambda>
    web3.eth.max_priority_fee + (2 * web3.eth.get_block('latest')['baseFeePerGas'])
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 660, in max_priority_fee
    return fee_history_priority_fee(self)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/_utils/fee_utils.py", line 45, in fee_history_priority_fee
    fee_history = eth.fee_history(*PRIORITY_FEE_HISTORY_PARAMS)  # type: ignore
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/eth.py", line 876, in fee_history
    return self._fee_history(block_count, newest_block, reward_percentiles)
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/module.py", line 57, in caller
    result = w3.manager.request_blocking(method_str,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 198, in request_blocking
    return self.formatted_response(response,
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/web3/manager.py", line 171, in formatted_response
    raise ValueError(response["error"])
ValueError: {'message': 'Method eth_feeHistory not supported.', 'code': -32000, 'data': {'stack': 'Error: Method eth_feeHistory not supported.\n    at GethApiDouble.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/geth_api_double.js:70:16)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at GethDefaults.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/gethdefaults.js:15:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.FilterSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/filters.js:89:7)\n    at SubscriptionSubprovider.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/subproviders/subscriptions.js:137:49)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at DelayedBlockFilter.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/delayedblockfilter.js:31:3)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at RequestFunnel.handleRequest (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/lib/subproviders/requestfunnel.js:32:12)\n    at next (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:136:18)\n    at Web3ProviderEngine._handleAsync (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:123:3)\n    at Timeout._onTimeout (/Applications/Ganache.app/Contents/Resources/static/node/node_modules/ganache-core/node_modules/web3-provider-engine/index.js:107:12)\n    at listOnTimeout (internal/timers.js:531:17)\n    at processTimers (internal/timers.js:475:7)', 'name': 'Error'}}
```

Its seems adding the code "gas_price" doesn't work in my case. Any suggestions about what I went wrong please?

Answer (score 2):

Solution found. The price of "gasprice" needs to be a capital.

```
transaction = SimpleStorage.constructor().buildTransaction(
    {
        "gasPrice": w3.eth.gas_price,
        "chainId": chain_id,
        "from": my_address,
        "nonce": nonce,
    }
)
```